# Error when doing request from Event Handler

Tags: web8.5, event-system

In our SDL Web 8.5 environment we have an Event Handler, which does a POST request to a .NET Core API (hosted on another server).

The request results in the following error:

> One or more errors occurred. An error occurred while sending the
>   request. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error
>   occurred on a send. Unable to read data from the transport connection:
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> Component: Tridion.ContentManager Errorcode: 0 User: NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

The interesting thing is that when I do the same request via Postman from the same server, the requests succeeds.

My code in the Event Handler looks like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(endPoint),
    Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20)
};

var x = client.PostAsync($"/api/{rootElementName}", content).Result;
```

Another interesting detail is that this does work on our development server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These servers have restricted which TLS version can be used. Adding the following line of code fixed the issue:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```